# Nginx - Search for static content in multiple directories?

Tags: nginx, webserver

Because of the way that our git repos are setup I have some static content that might be in one directory - and other content that might be in another directory. How can I ask nginx to search in two places for a static file like a stylesheet?

I originally thought that try_files had my answer - but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
try_files $uri /dir1/static/$uri /dir2/static/$uri @missing;
```

Comment: Three years later... same question. I love google.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
location ~* ^/just_test/(.+)$ {
    root /some/path/to/web/root;
    try_files /just_test/1/$1 /just_test/2/$1 /just_test/3/$1 @missing;
}
```

Comment: Turns out that the problem was the `root` directive which the try_files bases all paths by. I had my `root` too high and so my try_files was failing.

Comment: Hi, I can't make it work. `location ~* (.*\.html)$ {
    try_files /.tmp$1 /dist$1 =404;
  }` it does a directory index.

Comment: Are the paths in `try_files` relative (not absolute) to root , even though they start with `/`?

Comment: @MadsSkjern Yes, they are. The leading `/` is required even, because the paths are concatenated and without the leading `/`, there will be one missing in the final URL.